# How to delete firebase sub Collection's document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection

```
ledger{
 id:1234,
 name:Adam,
 subLedger:{id:099,credit:$200,debit:$0}
}
```

If i have to delete the ledger document then i am using

```
db.collection("ledger").doc("1234").delete();
```

which is working fine

But if want to delete its child collection or sub collection `subLedger` then i am using `db.collection("ledger").doc("1234").collection("subLedger").doc("099").delete();`

but it is not working

How can i delete the sub collection's document

[image: Ledger Collection]

I want to delete subLedger's Document in below picture
[image: delete subLedger's document]

Comment: 1) The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both. 2) Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of the document you're trying to delete in the console, making sure its entire path is showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting a complete document including its sub-collection is not possible in a singles request. So to delete a sub-collection we have to fetch the sub-collections and start deleting from child collection to parent collection. This is the way to delete entire collection

This [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#kotlin+ktx_2) will define it in more appropriate way